# Load Web Worker inside webpack library

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, webpack, web-worker

I am trying to load a web worker from inside a custom npm package.

`[App] -> [my npm package -> load worker]`

I use `worker-loader` inside the npm package to load the worker file:

```js
import Worker from 'worker-loader!./myPackage.worker';
const worker = new Worker();
```

My webpack config inside the local npm package:

```json
{
 entry: './packages/myPackage/src/index.ts',
  output: {
    library: 'myPackage',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './packages/myPackage/dist'),
    filename: "index.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.worker\.js$/,
        loader: 'worker-loader',
        options: {
          inline: "no-fallback"
      }
      },
    ]
  },        
}
```

Unfortunately every time I do so, my **app cannot locate the worker file**. The app is trying to get the worker from `./static/js/myPackage.worker.js` but the **file is not found** and an error is raised `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`.

What am I doing wrong here? Ideally I would like the **worker file to be bundled with the npm package so no additional file needs to be loaded**. How can achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem myself, based on when the post was made I'm going to assume you're using Webpack5.

First, I would change the order of rules and double-check their rules are matching. Second, since you're using `react-native` I would verify that you can use workers.

The easiest way to not create an additional file would be to use the [inline](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader#inline) option for the worker (There's a guide for TS with them too ). Please note, for a file not to be created `no-fallback` will have to be used as the value for the `inline` option.

If that isn't an option I would probably look into [module federation and the dynamic public path](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#offer-a-host-api-to-set-the-publicpath). If this as well is not viable then I would suggest looking into either `import.meta.resolve` or writing a plugin that can replace paths in the code after resolving in the Webpack dependency graph.

The `inline` option works like a charm, but hopefully, this helps if that isn't an option.

Cheers,
Chance